# Cross Browser Layout Help

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am having trouble creating an HTML5 cross browser template FF3+ and IE8+:

Specifications:

```
Width: 990px;
```

My navigation is on the left hand side using `<nav>` syntax

My navigation is inside a `div` with an id called `leftCol` this div  has a background called metalbg.

My content area is in a div called content.

My footer is in `footer` tags

Issue:

I am trying to create the css so if the site has "no scroll" the footer stays at the bottom and the site is "full hight" but if I have more content that requires a scroll the metalbg image will expand as well as the content area but then it must join back at the bottom.

I cannot seem to get both working.

Comment: It sounds like you have two issues here. The first one is trying to get the background to expand to the bottom of the page when the content expands. And the second is having the footer stay at the bottom of browser window at all times. The second may require Javascript to help support older browsers.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure. Do you want the footer to always be at the bottom of the browser window, or do you want it to be at the bottom of the page; if the content goes beyond the height of the browser window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to achieve this you should try the [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) technique by Ryan Fait.

This won't work however if you want the footer to stay at the bottom of the browser window even if the content is larger than the height of the browser window.

Comment: So far every sticky footer technique I've seen makes you set an absolute height for the footer, which for me has never been possible (variable content).

Comment: In this case the only solution I can think of without too much hassle is to use Javascript to calculate the height of the footer and change the CSS accordingly. I'm sure there are ways of doing this in pure CSS, but to make it cross browser compatible will most likely result in tears and loss of hair. :)